# Please how do I make multiple XMLHttpRequest in one js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, xmlhttprequest

[image: Http requests not fulfiled]
Good Morning my beautiful people please I need a help I am trying to make two http get requests and console log them but each time only one the first request response is logged on the console the second just keeps loading indefinitely.
`

```
function cacheobject(){
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest;
  req.open('get', 'http://localhost:3000/cache', false);
  req.send(null);
  console.log(req.responseText);
  return req.responseText;

};


function roomprcieCache(){
  let req = new XMLHttpRequest;
  req.open('get', 'http://localhost:3000/roomcache', false);
  req.send(null);
  console.log('My mumu don finish');
  console.log(req.responseText);

  return req.responseText;

};


cacheobject();
roomprcieCache();
```

`

Please what is the right way to make multiple requests in one js file

Comment: Try not to add an image of code, Please insert the complete code so we can help you better

Comment: Odds are the problem is with the server side code failing to send a response.

Comment: Passing `false` as the third argument to `open` is deprecated. Don't do it. Use a `load` event listener instead.

Comment: Noted, thanks Syed Arsalan Hussain I won't add an image in the future

Comment: Thanks, Quentin I will make the changes and see. The Server side is ok because using postman to send a request to the API returns the response.

Comment: I liked the way you started the thread "Good Morning my beautiful people please..."

Comment: Please [edit] to convert your images of text into actual text. [See here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) for why.

Comment: Please also see [ask], which instructs to explain your problem before showing code.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem as Quentin advised using a load event listener.

```js
  const cacheobject = () =>{
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/cache');

    req.onload = () =>{
      const data = JSON.parse(req.response);
      console.log(data);
    };

    req.send();
  }

  const roomprcieCache = () =>{
    const req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('GET', 'http://localhost:3000/roomcache');

    req.onload = () =>{
      const data = JSON.parse(req.response);
      console.log(data);
    };

    req.send();
  }

  cacheobject();
  roomprcieCache();
```